# Uploading application process

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to find out what is the specific file i need to upload using the Application loader and where can i find this file…

I though i should upload the .app.dsym file but it cannot be opened.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Open Xcode and then open the preferences. In the upper tab-bar click on 'Locations'.
You will now see where your IDE stores the derived data. (When you click on the small arrow the folder will open in Finder).

Now go to

> DerivedData/<YourApp>/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos.

The .app file in this directory has to be zipped and can then be uploaded via Application loader (If it is signed with a distribution certificate).

Comment: I know i've made a distribution certificate. How do i sign it with the certificate?

Comment: You can do that in the preferences of your project. See BuildSettings -> Code Signing Identity